# Replacing values in a Word table with values from an Excel table

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

Right now this is what I have for this project:

```
Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wordApp.Documents.Open (fileDirectory & "\" & "SingleTable.docx")
wordApp.Visible = True

Set wordDoc = wordApp.ActiveDocument

wordApp.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
wordApp.Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

For Each Cell In Worksheets("OldRates").Range("A1:I41")
    With wordApp.Selection.Find
        .Forward = True
        .Text = Cell.Text
        .Replacement.Text = "0000"
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne 'Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
Next Cell
```

What it's supposed to do is take the information from a table in Excel and put it into an already existing table in Word. The reason why I am using vba instead of copy/paste is because I want to maintain the formatting of the table. What happens is that at work I receive information in an excel file to update the Word tables. At work, the solution is to copy and paste, which destroys the alignment of the table and then to manually realign with format painter or indents etc.

**My problem** is that this code only takes the first value in the Range specified in the Excel worksheet and replaces it, but does not continue with the rest of the values. What do I need to add/change in order to fix this?

Comment: If it were possible to copy the table *from* Excel, while preserving formatting, would that be preferable?  (Otherwise, I'm not sure I understand the specific problem here)

Comment: Ideally I want to take an Excel table and have it replace a word table while keeping the exact format of the Word table.

Comment: In your case is it safe to assume that the Word Table is "selected" in Word when you run this macro from Excel?

Comment: Right off the bat I notice that while you're iterating a range of cells in Excel, you're doing no such explicit iteration in the Word document, instead you're using `wordApp.Selection.Find` inside the Excel loop. Are you sure this is going to do what you think it is?  It seems a better approach to locate & identify the *table* object in Word, and update it that way. (For starters, because `.Find` isn't going to guarantee that it finds the right instance of a word/number/value that may occur more than once in your Word document.  More detail & example data would be helpful...

Comment: Are you replacing entire table(s) with data from Excel? Or are you merely replacing *some* cell(s) in some table(s)? How many tables? Etc...